# jquery $('id').text with Bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery that changes the text of a link like so:

```
if (urlfind > 0) {
    $('#linkurl').text('More info');
}
```

And html:

```
<a href = "" id = "linkurl"></a>
```

I am trying to add bold to this link, but adding `<b>More Info</b>` leaves them escaped in the text itself, rather than making the text bold

Answer (score 5):

`.html()` sets string as HTML content, whereas `.text()` sets the string as text.

Write:

```
if (urlfind > 0) {
    $('#linkurl').html('<b>More info</b>');
}
```

OR

```
if (urlfind > 0) {
    $('#linkurl').html('<strong>More info</strong>');
}
```

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 2):

Or if you wanted to get extravagant (and somewhat unnecessary):

```
if (urlfind > 0) {
  $('#linkurl').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` method inserts text, while the `html()` method inserts HTML, and `<b>` tags are HTML

```
if (urlfind > 0) {
    $('#linkurl').html('<b>More info</b>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method by simply adding the style via the **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method:

```
if (urlfind > 0) 
{
    $('#linkurl')
        .text('More info')
        .css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F7rCF/)***